# BeautifulSoup html.parser not understanding img tag

Tags: html, image, beautifulsoup

Problem: `BeautifulSoup` is not understanding `img` tag as self closing when using `'html.parser'`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
BeautifulSoup('<img src="" alt="" title="" class=""><span>kjrn</span>', 'html.parser')
```

gives me

```
<img alt="" class="" src="" title=""><span>kjrn</span></img>
```

but I want the result to be

```
<img alt="" class="" src="" title=""/><span>kjrn</span>
```

I cannot use `xml` parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `lxml` instead.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup('<img src="" alt="" title="" class=""><span>kjrn</span>', 'lxml')
```

Outputs:

```
<html><body><img alt="" class="" src="" title=""/><span>kjrn</span></body></html>
```

`lxml` and `html5lib` will attempt to create a well formed document, that is why you are seeing html and body tags.

Read more about parsers [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers).

> There are also differences between HTML parsers. If you give Beautiful Soup a perfectly-formed HTML document, these differences won’t matter. One parser will be faster than another, but they’ll all give you a data structure that looks exactly like the original HTML document.

Comment: thanks a lot for your input. But it adding the extra `<html><body>...</body></html>` tags is why rejected it at first.

Comment: You can simply descard that by doing `print ("".join([str(item) for item in soup.body.contents]))`. Not an issue.

Comment: Solves the issue in the contraints of the question. thus accepting the answer. thank you @Zroq